# Asyncio testing a function which uses loop.call_soon_threadsafe

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have the following function:

```
def send_command(self, cmd):
    self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(
        functools.partial(
            self._transport.write, str(cmd).encode() + b"\n"
        )
    )
```

The system under test (sut) is a class inheriting from `asyncio.Protocol` which sends some commands to a piece of hardware on a socket. I have to use threads since this is part of a GUI under wxPython. Finally, if I call `self._transport.write` the code works fine on Linux but crashes on Windows™.

When running the test:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_send_command(self):
    self.sut._transport = Mock()
    self.sut.send_command("ook eek")
    assert self.sut._transport.write.called is True
```

I get an assert error. The `self.sut._transport.write` is never called. If I call `self._transport.write` directly in the function, the code crashes on Windows™ but the test passes just fine.

*What am I missing here?*

Anyone?…

Surely, this is not such an edge case…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A work around…

After [reading and experimenting with even loops](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#event-loop-implementations), using this:

```
import asyncio
import selectors

selector = selectors.SelectSelector()
loop = asyncio.SelectorEventLoop(selector)
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

by passes the problem. Of course, it means using a sub-efficient loop on Windows. ***☹ PHA!***

*Anyone with a better solution is welcome to some fake internet points.*